# Copying Mesh effectively

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've needed to copy a mesh with submeshes in case there are more than one material. I've came up with this code.

```
public static Mesh Copy(this Mesh original)
{
    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    original.CopyTo(ref m);
    return m;
}

public static void CopyTo(this Mesh original, ref Mesh copy)
{
    copy.name = original.name;
    copy.vertices = original.vertices;
    copy.normals = original.normals;
    copy.tangents = original.tangents;
    copy.triangles = original.triangles;
    copy.bounds = original.bounds;
    copy.uv = original.uv;
    copy.uv2 = original.uv2;
    copy.uv3 = original.uv3;
    copy.uv4 = original.uv4;
    copy.uv5 = original.uv5;
    copy.uv6 = original.uv6;
    copy.uv7 = original.uv7;
    copy.uv8 = original.uv8;
    copy.colors = original.colors;
    copy.bindposes = original.bindposes;
    copy.boneWeights = original.boneWeights;
    copy.indexFormat = original.indexFormat;
    copy.indexBufferTarget = original.indexBufferTarget;
    copy.vertexBufferTarget = original.vertexBufferTarget;
    copy.subMeshCount = original.subMeshCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.subMeshCount; i++)
    {
        copy.SetSubMesh(i, original.GetSubMesh(i));
    }
}
```

Do I miss something?
Also does it save any memory if I use CopyTo to reuse existing mesh?

Comment: `MeshFilter` might be what you're looking for https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter-mesh.html